# Add 0 to number with 5 characters (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column that contains:

```
 DATA
123456
12345
12345
123456
```

I would like to change this to:

```
 DATA
123456
012345
012345
123456
```

So if there are 5 characters in a cell, then add a 0 at the front of the number. What is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: Is the dtype numeric or str?

Comment: Are they already strings?

Comment: you want the end result as string, right?

Comment: Well that won't work, you can't represent ints with a leading 0, it'll have to be converted to a string

Comment: So I do : dfactual['DATA'].astype(str)

Comment: If you want to keep as int64 and not convert to text, you could just do something like:  `DATA.applymap( lambda x: '%06d' % x )`.  That formats the output rather than converting to strings.  Generally speaking it's more efficient to keep columns as integers than strings but I don't know what you are using this column for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the dtype for `DATA` column is `str`. You can use [`Series.str.rjust()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rjust.html) method. Example -

```
df['DATA'] = df['DATA'].str.rjust(6,'0')
```

If the dtype is `int` or numeric, to get this you would need to convert them to strings, using [`Series.astype()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) -

```
df['DATA'] = df['DATA'].astype(str)
df['DATA'] = df['DATA'].str.rjust(6,'0')
```

Demo -

```
In [33]: df['DATA']
Out[33]:
0    123456
1     12345
2     12345
3    123456
Name: DATA, dtype: object

In [34]: df['DATA'].str.rjust(6,'0')
Out[34]:
0    123456
1    012345
2    012345
3    123456
Name: DATA, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't keep the dtype as integer as you can't represent leading 0s in ints so you have to convert the dtype to str and then call the vectorised [`str.pad`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.pad.html#pandas.Series.str.pad) method:

```
In [11]:
df['data'] = df['data'].astype(str)
df['data'] = df['data'].str.pad(6, 'left', '0')
df

Out[11]:
     data
0  123456
1  012345
2  012345
3  123456
```

Comment: What a great and fast help!! Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [zfill](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill) function to pad with zeros:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'data': [123456, 12345, 12345, 123456, 123, 1]})
df['data'] = df.data.astype(str).str.zfill(6)
>>> df.data
0    123456
1    012345
2    012345
3    123456
4    000123
5    000001
```

Comment: Whilst this answer is correct we should actively discourage using `apply` where a vectorised solution exists, of course if the version of pandas is so old that the `.str` methods don't exist then this would be a valid answer